# Pull correct value as one variable depending on a condition

Tags: sql, join, sas, outer-join, case-when

Basically what I'm trying to do is say:
If there's a match on the key then insert the correct (new) value into a variable depending on the date. And if there isn't a match then I want the value from the old table The following is my sample code:

```
    proc sql;
create table fly.Formulary2017
as select
d.corp_ent_cd
,d.groupno
,case when p.EffectiveDate > d.cvmo
        then d.old
when p.EffectiveDate <= d.cvmo
        then p.new
else d.old
        end as WANT
,d.Key1
from lib.dsl d FULL JOIN lib.post p
on d.Key1=p.Key1
;   
quit;
```

So there won't necessarily be a match on every key. For the ones where there are no matches I want the old value.

Comment: Are the `Key1` values unique in the tables `lib.dsl` and `lib.post` ? What should happen when a key is repeated?

Answer (score 1):

you need to include matching records logic in your code as shown below. here is small sample code below.  I have assigned the "new" and "old" instead you can have columns instead.

```
 /***partial code.***/

case when d.Key1 = p.Key1  and p.EffectiveDate > d.cvmo
    then "new"
when d.Key1 ne p.Key1
 then "old"
  when d.Key1 = p.Key1 and  p.EffectiveDate <= d.cvmo
    then "old"


 /*full code to try*/

 data post;
input key1 EffectiveDate:date9. ;
 format EffectiveDate date9.;
datalines;
10 10OCT2018 
11 22OCT2018 
12 27OCT2018
15 10NOV2018
16 22NOV2018
 17 27NOV2018
;

data dsl;
input key1 cvmo:date9. ;
format cvmo date9.;
datalines;
10 17OCT2018 
11 1OCT2018 
16 22NOV2018 
17 27NOV2018 
;

proc sql;
select
p.key1,
, case when d.Key1 = p.Key1  and p.EffectiveDate > d.cvmo
    then "new"
when d.Key1 ne p.Key1
 then "old"
  when d.Key1 = p.Key1 and  p.EffectiveDate <= d.cvmo
    then "old"
    end as WANT

from dsl d FULL JOIN post p
on d.Key1=p.Key1
 ;   
quit;
```